# i want to calculate the distance using geodesic from geopy library

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, data-science, geopy

I have four lists of longitude and latitude

'''
shop_long = [-123.223, -127.223, -123.223, -123.048]

```
shop_lat = [49.1534, 55.1303, 49.1534, 53.2563]

cus_long = [-126.07325247944962, -126.07255765553835, -126.07485428820583, 
            -126.0733578858899, -126.07270416708549]

cus_lat = [51.29548801984406, 51.29486187466757, 51.29566033167437, 
           51.295612714656855]
distance = []
shop =  (shop_long, shop_lat)
customer = (cus_long, cus_lat)
print(geodesic(shop, customer).miles)'''
```

I want to calculate the distance between customer and shop using their latitude and longitude and append it into distance list. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from geopy.distance import geodesic


def main() -> None:
    shop_long = [-123.223, -127.223, -123.223, -123.048]
    shop_lat = [49.1534, 55.1303, 49.1534, 53.2563]
    shop_cords = [(lat, long) for lat, long in zip(shop_lat, shop_long)]
    cus_long = [-126.07325247944962, -126.07255765553835, -126.07485428820583,
                -126.0733578858899, -126.07270416708549]
    cus_lat = [51.29548801984406, 51.29486187466757, 51.29566033167437,
               51.295612714656855]
    cus_cords = [(lat, long) for lat, long in zip(cus_lat, cus_long)]
    cus_dists_to_shops = {
        f'cus_{cus_index}_dists': [f'{geodesic(cus, shop).km:.2f}km' for shop in shop_cords]
        for cus_index, cus in enumerate(cus_cords, start=1)
    }
    print(cus_dists_to_shops)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
{
    'cus_1_dists': ['313.23km', '433.62km', '313.23km', '300.35km'],
    'cus_2_dists': ['313.15km', '433.69km', '313.15km', '300.37km'],
    'cus_3_dists': ['313.32km', '433.58km', '313.32km', '300.41km'],
    'cus_4_dists': ['313.25km', '433.60km', '313.25km', '300.35km']
}
```

Comment: distance = []
for long , lat in zip(store_longitude, store_latitude) and  cus_long, cus_lat in zip(customer_longitude, customer_latitude):
    x = (lat,long)
    y = (cus_lat, cus_long)
    print (geopy.distance.geodesic(x, y).km)                                                                                                    I'm trying this . Is it right?